# prevent click on delegated anchor ONLY during animation of another element

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, anchor

So I've been looking for this and I still haven't found a solution without killing the anchor functionality all together.

I'm using an anchor tag to animate the fade-in and fade-out of some content DIVs. The bug comes when the user clicks another anchor tag while the animation of the previous is still happening and I end up with two DIVs stacked on top of each other. Other solutions I've found, kill the link function and renders them useless there after.  I need something that says while the animation of that DIV is going this anchor is useless. But once the animation completes, this anchor is functional.

I've tried

```
if ($("#" + visibleCtn).is(':animated')) {
     $("#modRightCol a").click('onclick', null);
    }
```

and

```
if ($("#" + visibleCtn).is(':animated')) {
     $("#modRightCol a").click(function(){
     return false
         });
     }
```

and this removes the buttons completely:

```
if ($("#" + visibleCtn).is(':animated')) {
     $("#modRightCol").undelegate("a", "click");
     return false;
    }
```

Here's code for showing and hiding:

```
$("#modRightCol").delegate("a", "click", function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var locInfo = $(this).attr("rel") + "Ctn";
            var locBtn = $(this).attr("rel") + "Btn";
            newCtn = $('#' + locInfo);

            //Change Map Location Button State
            cityLink.css('backgroundPosition','bottom');
            $(this).css('backgroundPosition','top');

            //Hide currently visible information
            allInfoCtn.each(function() {
                if($(this).hasClass('modActive')) {
                    visibleCtn = $(this).attr('id');
                } 
            }); 


            $("#" + visibleCtn).animate({
                        opacity: 0
                    }, 500, function(){
                         $("#" + visibleCtn).hide().removeClass("modActive").removeAttr("style");

                         //Show information related to location clicked
                        newCtn.show().animate({
                                opacity: 1
                            }, 500, function(){
                                newCtn.addClass('modActive');
                            });
                    }); //end animation function

           //Block clicks during animation              
           if ($("#" + visibleCtn).is(':animated')) {
                $("#modRightCol").undelegate("a", "click");
                return false;
            }

        });
```

Comment: Try to set global variable `isAnimated` and set it to `true` and `false` and then `preventDefault` or not

Comment: Thanks Tamlyn.  Where would I set the variable and then set the conditional statement?  Also the preventDefault would only prevent the href action and not the onClick call right?

Comment: Yeah, `preventDefault` prevent only default browser actions. If you want stop events you should use `stopPropagation`. Variable should be defined in top of scope, and condition should be set into event binding part.